# Xkill on open directory

Tags: xkill

I accidentally ran xkill on my file manager while my Documents folder was open. I can no longer see the directory, and I am told the directory no longer exists. Can I get the directory back or is it gone forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xkill` typically wouldn't delete files -- it only terminates a *process*. You may have ran `xkill` on your file manager window, which would have terminated the file manager (you can always start it again, this is temporary) but it would not have deleted any files.

Just to clarify, a [file manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_manager) is a program that lets you view your files, often graphically (as opposed to doing it in the terminal with `cd`, `ls`, etc.). Terminating the file manager with `xkill` would be similar to clicking the "X" button on the top of Windows Explorer (on Windows) or Finder (on Mac) for example -- it doesn't actually delete your files.

I'm assuming that you ran `xkill` on your file manager because it doesn't make sense to say that you ran `xkill` on a directory or file -- it can only operate on a *process* like a file manager. If you meant something else, please clarify and I'll try to help.

Comment: hi, yes I ran xkill on my file manager which was open on that particular directory. How do I get the directory back? I get the following error: error opening location: Error when getting information for file '/home/../Documents': No such file or directory

Comment: In gnu/linux, `..` (two dots) in a file path means "parent directory", i.e. `/a/b/c/..` would be equal to `/a/b`. So in your example `/home/../Documents` would be equal to `/Documents`, which is probably the wrong folder. You probably want to go to `~/Documents`, which is shorthand for `/home/<username>/Documents`, replacing <username> with your username. Can you try that directory?

Comment: oops yes I did already do that directory. I just omitted  my username from it.  `/home/<username>/Documents` does not exist

Comment: OK. Is it possible you accidentally drag and dropped or renamed your Documents directory into the trash or into another folder? It's unlikely that `xkill` deleted the folder by itself. I would look all over your `/home/<username>/` folder, and your Trash folder to see if you moved Documents. If you still can't find it, what version of Ubuntu are you using? And you are running as a normal user and not `root`, right?

Comment: Also, was there any ongoing copy / move operation going on while you ran `xkill`? If you were actively in the middle of copying a file while the program was killed that might have caused a problem. If you want to try to find your documents folder in a more advanced way, running `find ~ -name Documents` in your terminal should show if there's any folder named exactly "Documents" in your home folder, so e.g. if you dragged it to `~/Videos/Documents` then this command would find that.

Comment: I ran `find . -name Documents` and it seems that the folder ended up in trash after xkill somehow....problem solved. thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks! You might have accidentally pressed the Delete key or something while you were trying to get rid of the xkill cursor, which would have moved the folder to the trash. This was my first answer ever on askubuntu so I'm glad to have helped!